# Rate is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.Comparable

Tags: interface, comparable

I'm getting an error telling me that I am not implementing the compareTo method when I am. My code looks like this (I omitted the accessor methods since they are fine):

```
public class Rate implements Comparable
{ 
private int month;
private int day;
private int year;
private double rate;
private int a;  
private int b;
private int c;
private int d;

// The constructor method for the class
public Rate(int month0, int day0, int year0, double rate0)
{
    month = month0;
    day = day0;
    year = year0;
    rate = rate0;
}
public int compareTo(Rate obj) // @param obj the Rate object that will be compared another Rate object.
{
    a = (int)rate - (int)obj.getRate();
    b = year - obj.getYear();
    c = month - obj.getMonth();
    d = day - obj.getDay();

    if (a != 0)
        return a; // @return a The difference between rates for the two objects
    else if (b != 0)
        return b; // @return b The difference between years for the two objects
    else if (c != 0)
        return c; // @return c The difference between month for the two objects
    else if (d != 0)
        return d; // @return d The difference between days for the two objects
    else
        return 0; // @return 0 if the two objects are totally equal.

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
public class Rate implements Comparable
```

to this:

```
public class Rate implements Comparable<Rate>
```

Make sure that you override equals and hashCode, and that your equals method gives the same behavior as compareTo when two Rates are the same.  You'll experience subtle, counterintuitive bugs if you don't.

Comment: It's always the small things. Thanks a ton it works great now!